# Forcing immutability on an object

Tags: python

Before I start, I'm already aware that object immutability in Python is often a bad idea, however, I believe that in my case it would be appropriate.

Let's say I'm working with a coordinate system in my code, such that each coordinate uses a struct of X, Y, Z. I've already overloaded subtraction, addition, etc. methods to do what I want. My current problem is the assignment operator, which I've read cannot be overloaded. Problem is when I have the following, I do not want A to point to the same point as B, I want the two to be independent, in case I need to overwrite a coordinate of one but not the other later:

```
B = Point(1,2,3)
A = B
```

I'm aware that I can use deepcopy, but that seems like a hack, especially since I could have a list of points that I might need to take a slice of (in which case it would again have a slice of point references, not points). I've also considered using tuples, but my points have member methods I need, and a very large portion of my code already uses the structs.

My idea was to modify Point to be immutable, since it's really only 3 floats of data, and from doing some research _new _() seems like the right function to overwrite for this. I'm not sure how to achieve this though, would it be something like this or am I way off?

```
def __new__(self):
    return Point(self.x, self.y, self.z)
```

EDIT:
My bad, I realized after reading katrielalex's post that I can't modify a parameter of immutable object once it has been defined, in which case it's not a problem that both A and B point to the same data since a reassignment would require creation of a new point. I'd say that katrielalex's and vonPetrushev's posts achieve what I want, I think I'll go with vonPetrushev's solution since I don't need to rewrite all my current code to use tuples (the extra set of parentheses and not being able to reference coordinates as point.x)

Comment: "_immutably_ in Python is often a bad idea"? who says? seems like a bad starting place :-)

Comment: Sorry it can be just me, but i don't understand nothing , you talk about immutable and you say __in case I need to overwrite a coordinate of one but not the other later__ ??? in your first example you say you don't want two variable(label) refer to the same object ??? __variable are not what you thing they are by the way they are a sort of label in python like dictionary key__ , and when you say : __case it would again have a slice of point references, not points)__ sorry but i didn't get this part where is the problem ??? can you please __be more specific about what you want to do exactly__

Comment: Immutability is pretty well established as a *Good Thing™* across many, if not all, languages. Where did you get the idea that Python discourages immutability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In conjunction with katrielalex's suggestion, making the `Point` a named tuple would be good as well. Here I've just replaced the `tuple` parent with `namedtuple('Point', 'x y z')` - and that's enough for it to work.

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> class Point(namedtuple('Point', 'x y z')):
...     def __add__(self, other):
...             return Point((i + j for i, j in zip(self, other)))
...
...     def __mul__(self, other):
...             return sum(i * j for i, j in zip(self, other))
...
...     def __sub__(self, other):
...             return Point((i - j for i, j in zip(self, other)))
...
...     @property
...     def mod(self):
...             from math import sqrt
...             return sqrt(sum(i*i for i in self))
...
```

Then you can have:

```
>>> Point(1, 2, 3)
Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)
>>> Point(x=1, y=2, z=3).mod
3.7416573867739413
>>> Point(x=1, y=2, z=3) * Point(0, 0, 1)
3
>>> Point._make((1, 2, 3))
Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)
```

(Thanks to katrielalex for suggesting to extend the namedtuple rather than copying the code produced.)

Comment: -1 It is true that making the `Point` a namedtuple would be good, but the way to do that is to subclass a namedtuple not to copy-and-paste all the code from `collections.`

Comment: I think you're mistaking what `namedtuple` is. `namedtuple` is a factory function which produces classes - `Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y z')` is equivalent to that whole big `class` statement. `namedtuple` produces a class which is a direct descendant of `tuple`.

Comment: @Chris: I know. So you should do `named_Point = namedtuple(...)` to get a namedtuple class and then `class Point(named_Point): ...` to make a subclass with all the added methods. Notice I said "subclass *a* namedtuple" =).

Comment: @katrielalex: ah, I see. That would be neater.

Comment: I'm fine with this solution, especially now that it's been cleaned up, and no longer has the weird syntax of double-parentheses when declaring the point. Solution accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Point` a subclass of `tuple` -- remember, the built-in types (at least in recent Pythons) are just more classes. This will give you the desired immutability.

However, I'm slightly confused about your suggested use case:

> in case I need to overwrite a coordinate of one but not the other later:

That doesn't make sense if `Point`s are immutable...

---

```
>>> class Point(tuple):
...     def __add__(self, other):
...             return Point((i + j for i, j in zip(self, other)))
...
...     def __mul__(self, other):
...             return sum(i * j for i, j in zip(self, other))
...
...     def __sub__(self, other):
...             return Point((i - j for i, j in zip(self, other)))
...
...     @property
...     def mod(self):
...             from math import sqrt
...             return sqrt(sum(i*i for i in self))
...
>>> a = Point((1,2,3))
>>> b = Point((4,5,6))
>>> a + b
(5, 7, 9)
>>> b - a
(3, 3, 3)
>>> a * b
32
>>> a.mod
3.7416573867739413
>>> a[0] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Point' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: What's wrong with this: you lost the ability to get the point attributes by name (x,y,z), and you imported a module from inside a instance method.

Comment: @von: there's nothing wrong with importing a module within an instance method, although in this case I just did it as a shortcut in the interpreter. There's very little overhead to excess `import` calls, because they are cached in `sys.modules`. It's true that this doesn't have the ability to refer to attributes by name, though.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self._x=x
        self._y=y
        self._z=z

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            key={'x':'_x','y':'_y','z':'_z'}[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError
        else:
            return self.__dict__[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in ['_x','_y','_z']:
            object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
        else:
            raise TypeError("'Point' object does not support item assignment")
```

So, you can construct a Point object, but not change its attributes.

Comment: Your `raise` line is completely broken.

Comment: -1. An attempt to actually instantiate this will call the `__setattr__` which will raise a `TypeError`!

Comment: You're all right - this answer was wrong. I fixed the broken stuff, but I don't like this. Named tuples was the right thing to do.

Comment: You don't actually need the check in `__setattr__`; if I were doing it, the way I'd do it would be `object.__setattr__(self, '_x', x)` etc. in `__init__`. That highlights even more that it's not really immutable, and why extending `tuple` is better (and genuinely immutable).

Comment: @Chris - yes, you're right, the solution above can be optimized, but even then it is not really immutable.